# How to connect to remote deployment windows server in Jenkins Pipeline script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Pipeline to set the build and deployment process. For the build, i am using a Windows server node but for deployment, I have to use separate deployment servers (Windows machines) for Dev, QA and Production environments which cannot be added as slave nodes. I have to connect to these deployment servers to execute the deployment code. I have already tried using PowerShell and PSExec to connect to the remote machines and both are working fine, but our requirement is not to use any of these (PowerShell or PSExec) and do everything in Groovy scripting. I have searched everywhere but have not found a suitable solution to connect to the remote windows servers using Groovy in Jenkins Pipeline and run the deployment commands. Please suggest.

Comment: May I suggest [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/windows)?

Comment: I am not sure how Ansible is connected to this.

Comment: Ok, how your Groovy script should connect and manage those deployments? What do you deploy (MSI files, Jars, Wars, ...)? Is there a particular container that you deploy to like Tomcat? I've suggested ansbile cause I've seen it used as a deployment pipeline.